# Add opacity on card but disable it on icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show an icon when I hover on the card and add opacity on it but I don't want to add opacity to the icon.

Snippet:

```css
.cardrecipe_result{
    cursor: pointer;

}

.cardrecipe_result i{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #90CC57;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: none;
}

.cardrecipe_result:hover .card:not(i){
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.1s linear;
    border: 2px solid #57CBCC;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.cardrecipe_result:hover .card-body{

}
.cardrecipe_result:hover i{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 cardrecipe_result">
      <div class="card" id="recipe_id_108">
         <div class="">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><img onerror="imgErrorRecipe(this);" class="img-fluid" src="https://www.goodfoodtour.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2017/11/Buddha-Bowl-Sushi.jpg" alt="Recipe picture">
            <div class="card-body card_body_recipe">
               <h5 class="card-title">budha bowl brocoli, carottes, radis</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cardrecipe_result">
      <div class="card" id="recipe_id_142">
         <div class="">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><img onerror="imgErrorRecipe(this);" class="img-fluid" src="https://static.colruyt.be/culinair/Folderrecepten%201316%20+%20WM1416/linzenschotel%20met%20kerriegroenten_MR.jpg" alt="Recipe picture">
            <div class="card-body card_body_recipe">
               <h5 class="card-title">riz curry, lentilles, carottes</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cardrecipe_result">
      <div class="card" id="recipe_id_122">
         <div class="">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><img onerror="imgErrorRecipe(this);" class="img-fluid" src="https://img.cuisineaz.com/660x660/2013-12-20/i63062-photo-de-veloute-de-carottes.jpeg" alt="Recipe picture">
            <div class="card-body card_body_recipe">
               <h5 class="card-title">velouté de carottes</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove the opacity on the plus icon on hover ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra div you are having and simply target all the elements expect the `i` (note the use of a space in the selector)

```css
.cardrecipe_result{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cardrecipe_result i{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #90CC57;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: none;
}

.cardrecipe_result:hover .card :not(i){
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.1s linear;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.cardrecipe_result:hover .card {
    border: 2px solid rgba(87,203,204,0.5); /* use rgba here since it won't be affected by opacity */
}

.cardrecipe_result:hover i{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 cardrecipe_result">
      <div class="card" id="recipe_id_108">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><img onerror="imgErrorRecipe(this);" class="img-fluid" src="https://www.goodfoodtour.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2017/11/Buddha-Bowl-Sushi.jpg" alt="Recipe picture">
            <div class="card-body card_body_recipe">
               <h5 class="card-title">budha bowl brocoli, carottes, radis</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cardrecipe_result">
      <div class="card" id="recipe_id_142">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><img onerror="imgErrorRecipe(this);" class="img-fluid" src="https://static.colruyt.be/culinair/Folderrecepten%201316%20+%20WM1416/linzenschotel%20met%20kerriegroenten_MR.jpg" alt="Recipe picture">
            <div class="card-body card_body_recipe">
               <h5 class="card-title">riz curry, lentilles, carottes</h5>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cardrecipe_result">
      <div class="card" id="recipe_id_122">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><img onerror="imgErrorRecipe(this);" class="img-fluid" src="https://img.cuisineaz.com/660x660/2013-12-20/i63062-photo-de-veloute-de-carottes.jpeg" alt="Recipe picture">
            <div class="card-body card_body_recipe">
               <h5 class="card-title">velouté de carottes</h5>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution for this, would be to put icon out of `card` and give to icon `position: absolute.`

Comment: Pulling the icon out of `card` is most probably the best way, but `position: absolute` on the icon will not work. The outer container currently has absolute and therefore the icon will be positioned relative to the `row` container. There are more changes needed than just this.